# No content provider before streaming Video in VideoView

Tags: android, video

I have a question where i was trying to work on an example of showing video in a video view in the android device.

When i start the activity, in Log i get a no content provider exception and after i wait for 5 secs, the video starts playing and Logs getMetadata.

Why is that happening ?

here is a snippet i tried:

```
String videoUri = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
        uri = Uri.parse(videoUri);
        videoFrame = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.viewScreen);

        videoFrame.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoFrame.start();



06-16 16:31:18.167 26176-26176/com.example.testapp.videoapp W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4
06-16 16:31:35.106 26176-26176/com.example.testapp.videoapp D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
06-16 16:31:35.293 26176-26204/com.example.testapp.videoapp W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
```

Comment: Either their server is dodgy or your net connection is slow... Using Chrome on PC I got an error first time I tried your MP4 link. There was no page or data to load but afer refresh it works fine. So it could be a busy server or such other issue...